# Data is not get(Images & text) in phonegap application

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have phonegap app in old version.there its works fine but after i have build app using phonegap build its shows me some error i have resolve it and build app but i didn't get any data.

But i have check my app on local host its works fine. i am using rest client service to get data in json formate.i have also handeled cross domin error in my app it has no error.

when i have build my app i have error that is handeled by some changes in cofig.xml file changes are shown below.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
```

so i didn't get any clue.if any one have issue like this please tell me. i am using phonegap version cli-5.2.0 and andriod version 4.1.1.

Comment: are you building android app

Comment: yes i am build andriod app using phone gap build.

Comment: app is installing in device or not?

Comment: app is installing and i have developed in jquery.not in angular.

Comment: your issue may be have to add android permission in xml file

Answer (score 0):

@vatsal,
your issue is quite common. You have forgotten to set the version for your compiler. You can fix this by adding the version to your config.xml when you initially set out to build your Application. Also, if you DO NOT SET the version, you will get the latest version and a set of cascading errors.

***Below is what you need to know.***

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let's say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. This CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)